# to find the index number from a list based on the condition

Tags: java

How to find the index number of an object in list satisfying the condition

```
int index = list.indexOf(list.stream().filter(a-> a.getInfo().getDetails().getIndicator().equals("3")));
  list.remove(index)
```

I need to get the index value if the Indicator is 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you included `list.remove(index)` in the question code, if you want to *remove* an item that satisfies a condition, don't get the index then remove by index, just use [`removeIf(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```java
list.removeIf(a -> a.getInfo().getDetails().getIndicator().equals("3"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IntStream` to iterate the list based on index and get the index of satisfying the condition object

```
IntStream.range(0,list.size())
         .filter(i->list.get(i).getInfo().getDetails().getIndicator().equals("3"))
         .findFirst()
         .orElse(-1) // return -1 as default
```

Comment: This seems really silly. You've got your hammer (streams), and this take on finding the index is catching a fish. So now you're trying to toss that hammer into the lake and hope you hit a fish with it. Please. Just don't. Andreas's answer seems like a fine use of lambdas. Note that your approach is O(n^2) for linked lists, just for example (.get(n) is run every time, that's a real silly plan if .iterator() / ye olde reliable foreach is right there.

Comment: I'm really good with Andreas's answer and if OP intention is to delete the objects satisfying condition i will recommend him to use Andreas answer. But if we really want to get the index of object then i want to show this is the approach using streams @rzwitserloot

Answer (score 0):

With an oldschool iterator you can:

- remove matching elements while iterating
- remove all

  ```
    for(Iterator<YourType> it=items.iterator();it.hasNext();)
    {
        YourType element=it.next();
        if(element.getInfo().getDetails().getIndicator().equals("3"))
            it.remove();
    }
  ```